# Stripe PHP SDK Issue

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm having an issue with the below method and I think I'm doing something wrong.  Just looking for any guidance / oversights that someone might pick up on.  Thank you!

Per the API documentation:

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
  'sk_test_xxxxxxxxxx'
);
$stripe->accounts->createPerson(
  'acct_xxxxxxxxx',
  ['first_name' => 'Jane', 'last_name' => 'Diaz']
);
```

We're calling using the below where `$platformID` is a variable that holds the account ID and `$stripeData` is the array of person data. However we're getting a 500 error back but believe it's the SDK because our call isn't even making it to Stripe.

```
$stripeInteraction = \Stripe\Account::createPerson($platformID, $stripeData);
```

I just have a feeling I'm missing something silly but need another set of eyes.  I really appreciate any guidance!

Comment: Are you missing an email address?

Comment: Are you sure that function can be called in a static context properly? I.e. `\Stripe\Account::createPerson` vs `$stripe->accounts->createPerson`?

Comment: @msbit I did verify with the documentation that we can call it in the form we have.  But I could try the other way for sure.

Comment: `\Stripe\Account::createPerson` is the correct syntax for the static function, what does the error message you're getting from stripe-php say?

Comment: @PaulAsjes - That's the thing - we're just getting bad request but I think that is being generated by the SDK.  In the Stripe logs, I don't even see our request hitting them.

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: @PaulAsjes - We're just setting Server Error which I have to think is coming back from the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I am embarrassed to say I found the issue....it was a simple typo in one of the parameters within the array we were passing.  Sorry for the false alarm and sincerely appreciate the willingness to help!